# When executing API method using MediatR, getting an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

It is my 1st time implementing Mediator but now I get the following error when  calling API method:

**ERROR**

```
{"error":"Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync."}
```

**DI**

```
services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
```

**Base API**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediator;

    protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
}
```

**API**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("client/{clientId}/template/list")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TemplateListDTO>> GetClientTemplateList(long clientId)
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetClientTemplateListQuery { ClientId = clientId });
}
```

I am using DotNet core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it wasn't with Mediator. An exception occurred in the pipeline which was handled incorrectly and couldn't go to the next() pipeline.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you catch the exception in the startup? thank you.

Comment: @CidaoPapito, my problem wasn't on startup was unhandled expection in the pipeline process. I added an additional layer to it with a custom class so I had to catch the exception there

Comment: Is there any chance you share your code? I am not sure how to Add this Layer with a customs class to handle exception in the startup. I did try to add some TRY CATCH in the startup in other to catch the eventual exception but it did not happen. Any help I would appreciate.
My Error "with" Mediator just occurs when it is a JWT Authentication Controller. That is the strange part of the situation

Answer (score 2):

The issue is described here:

https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/317

> Ah. You can't do generic type constraints with vanilla
>   MS.Extensions.DI. See my PR to fix this:
>   https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/635

Do something like the following:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<CustomerAddRequest, CommandResponse>), typeof(CustomerAddBehavior<CustomerAddRequest, CommandResponse>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<BrandDeleteRequest, CommandResponse>), typeof(BrandDeleteBehavior<BrandDeleteRequest, CommandResponse>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<CustomerDeleteRequest, CommandResponse>), typeof(CustomerDeleteBehavior<CustomerDeleteRequest, CommandResponse>));
```